# how add and execute script and html to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to add a script  and some html to iframe or a div  the html & script tag is added but it does not execute

html

```
<script>
var gw_d = "ad1";
var gw_w = "300";
var gw_h = "250";
var gw_ad = "ad1";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<div id="ad1">
</div>
```

js.js

```
$("#" + gw_d).width(gw_w).height(gw_h);
$.get("/bw/" + gw_ad + ".txt", function(data) {

    $('<iframe>', {
    id:  'myFrame',
    frameborder: 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    width:gw_w,
    height:gw_h,
    }).appendTo("#" + gw_d).contents().find('body').append(data);

});
```

ad1.txt

```
<p align="center"> 
     <script  src="http://tag.contextweb.com/TagPublish/getjs.aspx?action=VIEWAD&cwrun=200&cwadformat=300X250&cwpid=504351&cwwidth=300&cwheight=250&cwpnet=1&cwtagid=18972"></script>
</p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5LNA/1/)

Comment: If the iframe is cross origin then you can not change the css nor html of the iframes content. See Cross Origin Policy

Comment: all files are loading from the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Scripts like that appears to break when `</script>` is included in the string. A workaround to that could be to add the elements through `dom` manipulation:

```
iframe = $('<iframe>');

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";

script.src   = "http://tag.contextweb.com/TagPublish/getjs.aspx?action=VIEWAD&cwrun=200&cwadformat=300X250&cwpid=504351&cwwidth=300&cwheight=250&cwpnet=1&cwtagid=18972"; 
// Or:
script.text  = "Your code here!"

iframe[0].appendChild(script);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5LNA/2/)**

Comment: the txt file can have any js and html it in, i need a  way to inject or load up that html js into iframe

Comment: Try first getting the contents from txt file. Separate the dom and js using regex or jquery. and then append them to iframe.

Comment: tried this but still not working

`var iframe = $('<iframe>');
iframe.id="myFrame";
 iframe.frameborder= "0";
   iframe.scrolling= 'no';
   iframe.width=gw_w;
   iframe.height=gw_h;
   
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";

script.src   = "http://tag.contextweb.com/TagPublish/getjs.aspx?action=VIEWAD&cwrun=200&cwadformat=300X250&cwpid=504351&cwwidth=300&cwheight=250&cwpnet=1&cwtagid=18972"; 
// Or:
//script.text  = "Your code here!"

//iframe[0].appendChild(script);

$("#" + gw_d).append(iframe)[0].appendChild(script);`

Comment: can you create the fiddle. Its defficult to find out whats the problem.

Comment: Use `iframe[0].appendChild(script);
iframe.appendTo('#subscribr'));`

Comment: text can be inserted but the script tag cannot be inserted check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/F5LNA/1/

Comment: Check the fiddle in answer

Comment: that is the issue the script is added but it is not executed.